# Java Application working sample not system.out

Tags: java

Where can I find a sample running application made from java and in netbeans IDE. I've been looking for sample but I keep getting sample with `System.out. What I want is the application samples such as a calculator or similar.

Comment: have you tried google?

Comment: actually i mention it already all i get is the sample that has system.out.printl..i keep searching but all i get is those sample i can run those system.out thing i want to learn how to run the application itself i mean the one with a form already and not just a console print out

Comment: You should search for java swing or awt applications

Comment: Search for java calculator awt or swing aaplication on google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Net Beans website

Sample Applications.

Ready-to-use sample applications are bundled with the NetBeans IDE. Create a new project (File > New Project) and select the Samples category.

These samples include a number of different applications including gui and Java EE

Comment: wait for 5 mins ill tick your answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [how-to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVYUqPVPloM) video, which explains a simple
example how to write a calculator application with netbeans and java.

There are plenty of tutorials.
Keywords I used to find examples: java, calculator, example, netbeans

[And here](http://searchengineland.com/guide/how-to-use-google-to-search) are some good tipps for google: